# np.array returning numpy.ndarray with "..."

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I created a script to generate a list:

```
import random

nota1 = range (5, 11)
nota2 = range (5, 11)
nota3 = range (5, 11)
nota4 = range (0, 2)

dados = []

for i in range(1000):

    dados_dado = []

    n1 = random.choice(nota1)
    n2 = random.choice(nota2)
    n3 = random.choice(nota3)
    n4 = random.choice(nota4)

    n1 = float (n1)
    n2 = float (n2)
    n3 = float (n3)
    n4 = float (n4)

    dados_dado.append (n1)
    dados_dado.append (n2)
    dados_dado.append (n3)
    dados_dado.append (n4)

    dados.append (dados_dado)
```

When i print `type (dados)` python return: `<type 'list'>`, a huge list that looks like this:

```
[[5.0, 8.0, 10.0, 1.0], [8.0, 9.0, 9.0, 1.0], [7.0, 5.0, 6.0, 1.0], [5.0, 8.0, 7.0, 0.0], [9.0, 7.0, 10.0, 0.0], [6.0, 7.0, 9.0, 1.0], [6.0, 9.0, 8.0, 1.0]]
```

I need to transform it to `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` so i made :

```
data = np.array(dados)
```

What i expected to return was something like this:

```
 [[ 6.8  3.2  5.9  2.3]
 [ 6.7  3.3  5.7  2.5]
 [ 6.7  3.   5.2  2.3]
 [ 6.3  2.5  5.   1.9]
 [ 6.5  3.   5.2  2. ]
 [ 6.2  3.4  5.4  2.3]
 [ 5.9  3.   5.1  1.8]]
```

But, what i get instead is:

```
 [[  7.  10.   6.   1.]
  [  8.   6.   6.   1.]
  [  6.   9.   5.   0.]
  ..., 
  [  9.   7.  10.   0.]
  [  6.   7.   9.   1.]
  [  6.   9.   8.   1.]]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you expect non-integer results in your numpy array, when they weren't in your list!?

Answer (score 1):

With your sample:

```
In [574]: dados=[[5.0, 8.0, 10.0, 1.0], [8.0, 9.0, 9.0, 1.0], [7.0, 5.0, 6.0, 1.
     ...: 0], [5.0, 8.0, 7.0, 0.0], [9.0, 7.0, 10.0, 0.0], [6.0, 7.0, 9.0, 1.0],
     ...:  [6.0, 9.0, 8.0, 1.0]]

In [575]: print(dados)
[[5.0, 8.0, 10.0, 1.0], [8.0, 9.0, 9.0, 1.0], [7.0, 5.0, 6.0, 1.0], [5.0, 8.0, 7.0, 0.0], [9.0, 7.0, 10.0, 0.0], [6.0, 7.0, 9.0, 1.0], [6.0, 9.0, 8.0, 1.0]]
```

convert it to an array, an see the whole thing.  Your input didn't have decimals to numpy display omits those.

```
In [576]: print(np.array(dados))
[[  5.   8.  10.   1.]
 [  8.   9.   9.   1.]
 [  7.   5.   6.   1.]
 [  5.   8.   7.   0.]
 [  9.   7.  10.   0.]
 [  6.   7.   9.   1.]
 [  6.   9.   8.   1.]]
```

Replicate the list many times, and print display has this `...`, rather than show 10,000 lines.  That's nice isn't it?

```
In [577]: print(np.array(dados*1000))
[[  5.   8.  10.   1.]
 [  8.   9.   9.   1.]
 [  7.   5.   6.   1.]
 ..., 
 [  9.   7.  10.   0.]
 [  6.   7.   9.   1.]
 [  6.   9.   8.   1.]]
```

The full array is still there

```
In [578]: np.array(dados*1000).shape
Out[578]: (7000, 4)
```

The default is for numpy to add the  ellipsis when the total number of entries is 1000.  Do you really need to see all those lines?

That print standard can be changed, but I question whether you need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is fine. NumPy just suppresses display of the whole array for large arrays by default.

(If you actually *were* expecting your array to be short enough not to trigger this behavior, or if you were actually expecting it to have non-integer entries, you'll have to explain why you expected that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
numpy.set_printoptions(precision=20)
```

Will give you more displayabilty, set precision as you desire.

Comment: this should show me all the results? i tried and i don't see any difference.

Comment: So increase the precision to the size of your array. Though I think the max might be 999.